# Show Tiff format image in Android

Tags: android

I am using `ImageView` to showing the .tiff formatted image, but I am getting error of `NullPointerException`.
I am converting the image file into byte array and then setting it in `ImageView`.
How can I show this tiff file?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9587 refer this link, this says android now doesn't support tiff file format

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the tiff image on a ImageView in android directly. http://code.google.com/p/tiffonandroid/source/browse/  
 this is a sample tiffviewer. This might help you

Answer (score 0):

Tiff has images stored as rows of bytes starting at defined offsets. So you can easily retrieve single rows to build the full image. 
If you open any tif file in hex editor you will see that first 4 bytes mark tiff by code. And next 4 bytes give offset for metadata about tif image.
Use random access file to open image tif file, then seek the offset and you land into metadata space.From here you can pick offset of required image rows. Then go and get it..

If we needed full load of image like jpeg or BMP, then collect and combine all these rows after decompression, if any. Then you will get the full image