# How to show .Tiff file into ImageView?

Tags: android, android-imageview, tiff

I have tried to show .tiff formatted file into Imageview by using different image loader library. but i didn't get success.

Q.1 Does anyone has idea to show .Tiff file into imageview?
Q.2 Is there any third-party library available to load .Tiff image?
Q.3 Which image types are supported by Android Image View?

Comment: below links might be helps to you
    [link1][1]
    [link2][2]
    [link3][3]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498967/show-tiff-format-image-in-android
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488958/display-tiff-format-image-in-android-app
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469676/imageview-not-display-android

Comment: A.1 Write code to decode a TIFF file into a `Bitmap`. Or, write code to convert a TIFF into a supported file format. A.2 Asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. Q.3 [JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP, and WebP](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

Comment: Why can't you convert a TIFF file to a PNG or JPEG?

Answer (score 0):

There's a library to have a tiff file viewer on android system:
https://code.google.com/p/tiffonandroid/

Media supported by Android are:
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html